# How to detect Genuino 101 from inside the code?

Tags: arduino-mega, core-libraries, arduino-galileo, avr-gcc

I am using a custom library for Arduino Mega which uses [AES library](https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib) for AES-128 encryption.

However, when I try to use that library in Intel Genuino 101 development board, it shows compilation error which is because the assembly language written in AES library was compatible with Atmel devices only.

And my question is whether there is a way, my code can automatically detect the GENUINO board by writing some sort of signature verification of this board and hence I can exclude the encryption part if it can successfully detect GENUINO 101.

For any queries, feel free to bug me, thanks.

Comment: No, you do not want _your code_ to detect the Genuino 101. Your code cannot run until is is compiled. You want _the compiler_ to detect whether it is compiling for an AVR-based Arduino or for something incompatible (whether it's ARC, ARM or Intel is irrelevant). What you want is called [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation), and that is what KIIV's answer is about.

Comment: Yeah, True. Pardon me for the misunderstanding. This is what I exactly asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino defines some macros so you can use [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation). For example these are from boards.txt:

- use `ARDUINO_AVR_PROMICRO` if it's specific for board variant
- use `ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR` if it's specific for Arduino with AVR

Also avr-gcc defines macros according to cpu settings (this should be similar for other platforms too):

- use `__AVR_ATmega32U4__` if it's specific for only one MCU
- use `__AVR__` if it's compatible with all AVR based MCUs

And code examples:

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega88__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega328__)
// something for ATmegaXX8 family...
#else
// ...
#endif

#ifdef __AVR__ 
// Code related to AVR
#else
// Code for other architectures
#endif
```

More about [predefined macros in avr-gcc](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/using_tools_1using_avr_gcc_mach_opt.html).

Comment: Since the library seems to be compatible with all AVR-based Arduinos, it is probably best to test for `#if __AVR__` (or `#ifdef __AVR__`) rather than for specific MCUs.

Comment: @KIIV I tried #if defined __AVR__ and it accepts, but for #if defined(__AVR_ATmega328__), I could not find the expected solution. Can you suggest any link which explains more on this?

Comment: @goddland_16 That was an example. Arduino MEGA 2560 uses `__AVR_ATmega2560__`. You can check label on the MCU.

Comment: The correct Arduino architecture macro is `ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR`, not `DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR`.

Comment: @per1234: Fixed, copy&paste error as usual...

Comment: @KIIV yeah checked it. Working and for UNO it is [__AVR_ATmega328P__] .